# Get Results view from different jenkins dashboards in 1 single jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get a jenkins dashboard view from a jenkins instance running in isolated cloud and add this view in another jenkins dashboard to have results from multiple jenkins in one place.
Is there any way to do that by use of a specific plugin or by directly copying files to the main jenkins folder (Tried by adding a job folder directly in jenkins/jobs folder -> didnt work).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the same:
In jenkins folder, there is a file - config.xml. There we change each list view which gives a view and the job names there specifies which jobs are listed in this particular view.

```
<listView>
      <owner class="hudson" reference="../../.."/>
      <name>XYZ</name>
                ..
      <jobNames>
                ..
      </jobNames>
      <jobFilters/>
      <columns>
        <hudson.views.StatusColumn/>
                ..
      </columns>
      <includeRegex>Deploy.*</includeRegex>
      <recurse>false</recurse>
    </listView>
```

We modify the config.xml in the main jenkins server to include the new view(with specified job names) and we need to copy all jobs folders to the main jenkins. Then restart jenkins to see the modified dashboard.